# JSF login failing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

Im new to developing with Java & JSF (this is part of Uni studies);
I'm using NetBeans 8.2, GlassFish 4.1.1 (with Derby DB), JSF 2.2:

While my login is failing authentication via a jdbcRealm which I can't figure out), its also never redirecting to my authFailure.xhtml page either & just reloads the login page.

Looking in the GlassFish logs, I simply have a message saying " 
jdbcrealm.invaliduser"

My database has the following data:
--EMAIL-----------PASSWORD-----------APPGROUP
webmaster--5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99--ADMIN
staff1--5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99--USER

Ive used MD5 hashing to encrypt the word "password"

My login.xhtml page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="NDIS Management System"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Danielle Walker"/>

        <title>NDIS Home</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/the-big-picture.css"  />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/google-button.css" />
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <f:verbatim>
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->    
        </f:verbatim>

        <f:verbatim>
            <script>
                var googleUser = {};
                var startApp = function () {
                    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                        // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
                        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                            client_id: '.....apps.googleusercontent.com',
                            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
                                    // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                                    //scope: 'additional_scope'
                        });
                        attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
                    });
                };

                function attachSignin(element) {
                    console.log(element.id);
                    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
                            function (googleUser) {
                                document.getElementById('name').text = "Signed in: " +
                                        googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId();
                                //document.getElementById('login:j_username').value = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
                            }, function (error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
                        //alert("Opps... an error Occured");
                    });
                }
                function signOut() {
                    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                        console.log('User signed out.');
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </f:verbatim>
        <ui:insert name="head"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body class="full">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <div id="gSignInWrapper" style="padding-top:5px;">
                                <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn" style="float: right;">
                                    <span class="icon"></span><span class="buttonText">Sign In</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span style="color:#f9f9f9"><div id="name"></div></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

        <h:form id="login" onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action = 'j_security_check';" prependId="false">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username" />
                <h:inputText id="j_username" />            
                <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
                <h:inputSecret id="j_password" />
                <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Login" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
        <script>startApp();</script>

        <ui:insert name="body"/>

        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h:outputScript name="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

My Web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <!--<welcome-file>faces/admin/mainmenu.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>faces/user/usermenu.xhtml</welcome-file>-->
        <welcome-file>/faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/faces/authFailure.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>NDIS-Admin</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>ADMIN</web-resource-name>
            <description>ADMIN</description>
            <url-pattern>/faces/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>NDIS-User</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>USER</web-resource-name>
            <description>USER</description>
            <url-pattern>/faces/user/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/authFailure.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>NDIS-Admin</description>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>NDIS-User</description>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ttf</extension>
        <mime-type>css/fonts</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>otf</extension>
        <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>font/woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>font/woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My faces-config.xml file;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <application>  
        <!-- This supports resources referenced from within css files e.g. url(../fonts/glyphicons) -->
        <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    </application>
    <navigation-rule>
        <description>Administrator Main Menu</description>
        <from-view-id>/admin/mainmenu.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>logout.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <description>User Main Menu</description>
        <from-view-id>/user/mainmenu.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>logout.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
 </faces-config>
```

And my jdbcRealm config:  (its not showing, but Digest Algorithm is set to MD5)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own issue :-)
I was missing a beans.xml & then did a clean build and it all worked.